# md-autocomplete select by object value

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material, md-autocomplete

Do you guys know of a way to have md-autocomplete select based on the value of one object parameter?

I want to preselect some data in my autocompletes on loading of my data.

So for instance the data I get from my server is:

```
{"building": "0015", "room": "0113", "available": true}
```

But the buildings list of my autocomplete might look like this:

```
[{"Value": "0015", "DisplayValue": "Offices"},{"Value": "0813", "DisplayValue": "factory"}]
```

Is there a way to have my autocomplete preselect the "Offices" building if I pass it the "number" parameter?

My html looks like this:

```
<md-autocomplete ng-disabled="!vm.edit.value" md-selected-item="vm.activityData.building"
                         md-items="item in vm.getList('Buildings')"
                         md-search-text="vm.autocompleteTexts.Buildings"
                         md-selected-item-change="vm.setAutocompleteValue('building')"
                         md-item-text="item.DisplayValue" md-min-length="0"
                         md-no-cache="true" md-select-on-match="true"
                         md-delay="100"
                         md-floating-label="Building"
                         md-dropdown-position="bottom">
            <md-item-template>
                <span>{{item.DisplayValue}}</span>
            </md-item-template>
            <md-not-found>
                No values found
            </md-not-found>
        </md-autocomplete>
```

getList is like this

```
getList(listname: string): any[] {
        return this.serverdata.Lists[listname].filter(
            (item) => {
                return item.DisplayValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.autocompleteTexts[listname].toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            });
    }
```

setAutocompleteValue doesn't do anything yet, but it exists, this will be used for some autocompletes where they have to populate other fields after changing selections.

Since "item in array" is standard angular expression, I thought I could expand it with track by, but that doesn't work sadly...

Comment: Please post your code what you did so far.

Comment: @MaximShoustin there you go!

Comment: Check if its helpful: https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/yoKgvp?editors=1010

Comment: @MaximShoustin no I only know the number, I don't have the whole object to select with.

Comment: only number parameter or displayvalue parameter also? (for search purpose)e.g. you want to see "Offices" as autocoplete when you type "0015" in input field right ? (Also when you select some option from autocomplete options what you want to show, number or displayvalue in input field?)

Comment: @Shantanu Just preselect the value with the number parameter, when typing I will only search on DisplayValue.